# Расшифровка свойств

Tags: bootstrap

Как расшифровываются эти свойства `mb-md-0` `me-md-auto` Bootstrap 5.2 ?

```
      <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center mb-3 mb-md-0 me-md-auto text-dark text-decoration-none">
        <span class="fs-4">Simple header</span>
      </a>
```

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/spacing/

Comment: @AlexeyTen спасибо, как раз это и смотрел, но не мог понять что такое `d` - а оказалось это просто точка останова `md` xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это стандартные брейкпоинты Bootstrap, которые задают внешние отступы (`margin` в CSS) для элементов.

`mb-md-0` - говорит нам о том, что для размеров экрана **≥ 768px** отступ вниз от элемента будет равен 0, т.е. `margin-bottom: 0`

`me-md-auto` - здесь нам говорится о том, что для размеров экрана **≥ 768px** будет использовано свойство `margin-right: auto`. Ключевое слово `auto` даст левой стороне долю оставшегося пространства.